Getting "[object Object]" when uploading the .pdf file from browser through multer
basically the title that I'm getting nothing from the browser and also postman, I cannot even see print the console.log statements because it just stuck on object Object.
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");

// Multer configuration
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: path.join(__dirname, "../public/uploads/"), // Destination folder for uploads
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(
      null,
      file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname)
    );
  },
});

// Multer instance for single file upload
const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: { fileSize: 5000000 }, // 5MB file size limit
}).single("filePath"); // 'filePath' should match the name attribute in your HTML form input

module.exports = upload;

my html file name tag is the same as "single("filePath");
I have tried doing changes that i first included multer config in directly app.js file then in the controller which was using it then a separate file and i got the same result.
This below is my folder structure


Edited version 22/6/24
const { formdata } = require("../models"); // Import the formdata //model
const upload = require("../config/multerconfig");

exports.uploadFile = (req, res, upload) => {
  // const userId = req.session.userId;

  upload(req, res, async (err) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: err });
    }

    if (!req.file) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "No file selected!" });
    }
    // console.log("Uploaded file:", req.file); // Log the uploaded file details
    // console.log("Uploaded file path:", req.file.path); // Log the path of the uploaded file
    // console.log("Uploaded file original name:", req.file.originalname); // Log the original name of the uploaded file
    console.log("Uploaded file:", JSON.stringify(req.file, null, 2));

    // Alternatively, log specific properties of the file object
    console.log("Field Name:", req.file.fieldname);
    console.log("Original Name:", req.file.originalname);
    console.log("Encoding:", req.file.encoding);
    console.log("MIME Type:", req.file.mimetype);
    console.log("Size:", req.file.size);
    console.log("File Path:", req.file.path);

    res.send("File uploaded successfully");
    try {
      // const filePath = path.join("/uploads", req.file.filename);
      const filePath = req.file.path;
      await formdata.create({ sessionid, filePath });

      res.status(200).json({ message: "File uploaded successfully", filePath });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Error saving to database:", err);
      res.status(500).json({ message: "Server error" });
    }
  });
};

23/6/24
solved the problem by changing the controller function and calling it from app.js directly instead of using router. and integrated that multer configuration inside the app.js file.
Don't know if its a correct fix or Diy fix but now there are no problems storing the file path in the database.
Idk how to close this post as I don't have the option. Kindly close it, Barmar. Thanks for your help

Are you uploading with a normal form or AJAX?

This is probably a client-side problem. [object Object] comes from the browser when you use an object where a string is expected.

I am using normal form and i am using express at the backend to fetch the data from HTML form.

@Barrmar can you explain what can i do to solve this problem?

Where exactly do you see [object Object]?

basically i signin then i upload a pdf file from browser which is then stored in my publics/upload folder then my vscode terminal and browser shows "[object Object]".
the backend doesn't proceed from there and is stuck. what it needs to do more is that after storing the file in uploads directory, it will write the filePath of uploads in mysql database along with userId.

What's displayed in the browser coming from the res.send() code in the controller function.

all white screen which is saying "[object Object]" on top left, whether i comment the res.send() or not it does not matter. vscode terminal also keep showing this in red colour.

The problem is in your controller, not the multer code. It's returning an object instead of text.

Something like res.send('File uploaded successfully') should show that message. If that's not happening, there's some other problem. But we need to see the controller.

If possible can you please show the whole codes, somewhere in github? The organisation of the codes also to be checked.

@ViNtr0 you should include controller code as suggested, or you can also answer your own question
